# How to hide one property from one of the derived class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, polymorphism

I have a scenario where my base class(`Employee`) contains few properties and it has two subclasses(`PermanentEmployee` and `ContractEmployee`). Now there is a one property which is a part of only PermanentEmployee (MedicalCoverage). And I am deciding the type of employee on runtime using polymorphism so I need to have MedicalCoverage property to be a part of base class only so that I can access it in client code accessing employee object. I don't want want ContractEmployee to have this property So how Can achieve this or any alternative for this design.
The base class employee looks like this

```
     Public Class Employee
        Public EmployeeId As Integer
        Public EmployeeFirstName As String
        Public EmployeeLastName As String
        Public Salary As Integer
        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property bonus As Double
          Get
             Return Salary
          End Get
       End Property
    End Class
```

I want to have MedicalCoverage to be a part of permanentEmployee

```
Public Class PermanantEmployee
    Inherits Employee

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property bonus As Double
        Get
            Return 15 * Salary
        End Get
    End Property
   Public Property MedicalCoverage As Double 'The property to be accessed only here
End Class
```

The contract Employee looks like this

```
    Public Class ContractEmployee : Inherits Employee

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property bonus As Double
            Get
                Return 12 * Salary
            End Get    
        End Property
       'The MedicalCoverage property is not part of the class here
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. You can't. It is the nature of inheritance.
If something is Employee and the employee has a property MedicalCoverage then any class inherits from Employee will has this property.
But just a quick mind game. What should do the program if you store a ContractEmployee in a variable typed as Employee and try to access the MedicalCoverage property?
If you insist this idea than you can define the proeprty in the Employee as virtual and override it within the ContractEmployee and throw an exception that this proeprty is not supported in this instance.
If you create an interface you still can't access that property through Employee typed variable and still has to cast to interface type, so you could just add that property in the PermanantEmployee and if the instance is PermanentEmployee you can cast to it to access the property.

Comment: very much helpful. Thanks @Péter

Answer (score 0):

This question is more opinion based. But if i were to implement this, i will use the "is" operator to decide whether to invoke the property.

```
if emp is PermanantEmployee then
     (emp as PermananantEmployee).MedicalCoverage = 12.00
```

Comment: Yes thats fine I will access like that but question is I don't want MedicalCoverage to be part of ContractEmployee class and also I want Medical coverage to be inherited from Employee. SO how do I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want that in Employee, when it is not a valid property for it.

Comment: So that if in future contract employee gets medical coverage I can just use it. I am not sure if we could hide in a such way but I want to know if there is any better approach

Comment: Then i guess currently the ContractEmployee can have a MedicalCoverage property and can return 0.0, and in future you can change the value.

Comment: This is the only possible solution with the "has a relationship". If you want to implement this separately , then you should wrap the MedicalCoverage property in an interface and implement it only for PermanantEmployee. Once the ContractEmployee gets a MedicalCoverage scheme, implement the interface in the ContractEmployee class as well.

Comment: Yes we can do this way. Thanks